# Count multiple columns and total in a new column

Tags: sql

Im looking to count numeric values across multiple columns with the total in a new column called 'car_total'

I tried a select case stmt but no success

The result should look like:

```
|car_id | merc | toyota |  fiat | car_total
+-------+------+--------+-------+----------
|123567 |    1 |      0 |     0|         1
|567888 |    0 |      1 |     1 |         2
```

Comment: What was the "select case" you tried, and what *precisely* was the problem with it?

Comment: Add sample data, expected output and preferable also what you have tried to your question but _as text and not as images_. Also tag your question with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Hint:  `merc + toyota + fiat`.

Comment: Your question is unclear, you say you want to count numeric values but 0 is also a value? Do you mean to _add_ values or count values that match some condition(s) like not zero or not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT car_id, 
   merc, 
   toyota, 
   fiat, 
   Sum(merc + toyota + fiat) AS car_total 
FROM   table_name
```

OR

```
SELECT car_id, SUM(mers+toyota +fiat ) AS car_total FROM Cars Group By Id
```

Comment: With the select sum the car_total is 1386.  The select has summed the merc, toyota, fiat in the car total but i need the car_total broken down by car_id

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the result as its in sql azure with the real column names

Comment: have you tried this `SELECT Id, SUM(merc+toyota +fiat ) AS car_total FROM Cars Group By Id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sql query to get the total in new column

```
SELECT 
   car_id,
   merc,
   toyota,
   fiat,
   (merc + toyota + fiat) as car_total
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Apologies, its COUNT I'm seeking instead of SUM.   The below doesn't cause an error but the result is wrong.                                
 SELECT car_id, merc, fiat,
COUNT (merc + fiat) 
AS car_total
FROM t1;